# Excel - Is it possible to make a drag and drop function to save files directly into a folder?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, drag-and-drop, power-query

I am working on a EDMS system which is to be created in Excel. Could anyone clarify whether or not it is possible to drag and drop files directly to the folder path THROUGH Excel? Instead of accessing the folders all the time, my project managers could really benefit of such a function.

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Yes Excel VBA can facilitate you to drag file form Tree view to Folder !!

Comment: Do you have any knowledge on how to do this? It would be much appreciated! Right now I have a query created from a folder located on a shared network drive which shows all the files located there. It could be really cool if it was possible to drag files directly into these different folders trough Excel without accessing them manually.

Comment: Give me some time to test the available VBA code, soon I'll return to the post. ☺

Comment: I've VBA code ready & working properly will help you to MOVE specific files from one to another folder, instead of DRAG them ! Will this work for you, just confirm  so that I can post it here !! ☺

Comment: Sure, let me give it a try! :-)

Comment: Check the code I've posted just now after I've  tried it successfully. ☺

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MoveFiles()

    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xTFile As String
    Dim xExtArr As Variant
    Dim xExt As Variant
    Dim xSPath As String
    Dim xDPath As String
    Dim xSFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long

    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFd.Title = "Please Select Original Folder:"

    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xSPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Right(xSPath, 1) <> "\" Then xSPath = xSPath + "\"
    xFd.Title = "Please Select Destination folder:"

    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xDPath = xFd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Right(xDPath, 1) <> "\" Then xDPath = xDPath + "\"
    xExtArr = Array("*.xlsm*", "*.Docx")

    For Each xExt In xExtArr
        xTFile = Dir(xSPath & xExt)

        Do While xTFile <> ""
            xSFile = xSPath & xTFile
            FileCopy xSFile, xDPath & xTFile
            Kill xSFile
            xTFile = Dir
            xCount = xCount + 1
        Loop
    Next
    MsgBox "Total number of moved files is: " & xCount, vbInformation, "Move File(S)"
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Copy & Paste this Code as Standard Module.
- RUN the Macro.
- It open the Explorer & prompt you to select 
  Original (Source) Folder.
- Select the Folder & Press OK.
- Again it prompt you to select the Destination 
  Folder.
- Press Ok, soon you get Message Box that how 
  many Files been copied.

**Note:**

- This line is editable `Array("*.xlsm*", "*.Docx")`, you may replace
  `File extensions` with other, as per your need.